What industrial footprint is needed to manufacture ample medieval-era work uniforms?
I'm a time traveler from 2024 who has set myself up in the medieval era as a local lord, and I wish to provide cheap, high-quality uniforms for laborers in my lands, namely: unisex tunics, and hooded, water-resistant cloaks for the rainy season, all in a reasonable variety of sizes. I don't need the modern variety of colors and styles; I just want to provide something genuinely sufficient for daily living and especially work.
I've arranged to have modern automated textile machinery sent back from the future, that can be used to convert raw cotton to finished clothing products, but I need to run as lean as possible, i.e. as few as possible of each kind of machine. I want end-to-end automation.
Using real technology only, what machines do I need, and how many of each? Which steps of this process can be fully automated, and which will require human operators? How many units of clothing can I expect this setup to produce, and how much raw cotton do I feed it? I'm looking for an answer that describes the vital elements of a minimal production pipeline, and which speaks to inputs, outputs, and throughput.
Real-world textile tech and know-how only. No AI or matter fabrication or magic.
Some points of additional clarification:

I'm not looking to replace all textile production in my area, I just want to add a supply of serviceable uniforms. I assume tailors and other tradespeople will continue to produce all the other things, from undergarments to dress clothes to extreme-weather gear.
I do hope my clothing will be objectively better than what is available elsewhere. I assume much of that will come from better-spun thread, higher threadcounts, and having ubiquitous fabric.
There is no financial motive here; I'm not interested in ways to overproduce or sell excess byproducts in the pipeline.
I have as much electricity as needed, but just barely.
I can obtain replacement parts from the future occasionally, but I can't source any of my production inputs from the future.
Cotton for sure, picked by hand. Wool is also plentiful, so if that can be added to the menu easily, please do.


This is a big ask. What's the number of people expected to be clad at what rate? There's many steps here I'm wondering if each warrants it's own question. Do things like supplies of: electricity, bleach, dye, mordant and the up-skilling of the workforce to be able to effectively use sewing machines count at all? Not to mention clean water too.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I don't know enough about the topic to provide some of those specifics. Don't worry about electricity. Bleach and dye are covered by "inputs that can't be resupplied from the future," so I'll need an expert to tell me whether they are vital or nice-to-haves. As far as target output, I was hoping to invert that, and find out is the expected production of a minimal pipeline, i.e. what rate do we get with just 1 of whatever machine works slowest? I'm looking for the yield of the smallest footprint at the biggest-scale tier.

I suspect that just packing a few thousand cloaks and tunics would be considerably lighter and cheaper than the equipment you need to produce them.

The most cost-effective part to import might be the dye for the fabrics. A few Kg of ago dyes might be enough to give a small army a unique look. Everything else could be done using native technologies.

(1) Cotton was not available in any kind of quantity in medieval Europe, or really anywhere outside India. (2) A hundred thousand tunics and a hundred thousand cloaks are very much easier to transport than the automated machines to separate the cotton fibres from the seeds (which was by far the most significant bottleneck in cotton cloth production in pre-modern times), and then spin the fibres into thread. The machines to weave the thread into cloth, cut and sew the cloth can then account for another hundred thousand tunics and cloaks.

@RichardKirk: Cloth was very expensive in medieval times. Going into a random large village and asking for a thousand shirts would make the village happy for steady employment for years.

It's much cheaper to just directly import clothes.
Clothes for a few thousand people might weigh a ton or two. A single machine probably weighs that much.
Just import as much as you can with your machine budget, and then work on bolstering your economy. Sheepskins, as is before any processing, are pretty water resistant because they have Lanolin in them. You don't need advanced future tech for this, just normal farmers sheering sheep.

Upvoted. One thousand cotton tunics weigh maybe half a tonne. Plus one thousand cloaks, say a tonne and a half. That's one remarkably tiny cotton yarn spinning machine. (I have never seen one so small, so it must be a bespoke order.) Add the cotton gins to separate the cotton fibres from the seeds, the automated looms to weave the yarn into cloth, the automated cutting machinery, the automated sewing machines (which don' really exist)...

This answer is categorically ineligible to be selected because it does not answer the question. I did not ask "what's the best way to provide uniforms," I asked what machinery would be required to start producing uniforms.

@Tom: Just to be helpful: you need cotton gins to separate the fibers from the seeds; spinning machines to spin the fibers into yarn; power looms to weave the yarn into cloth; cutting machines; sewing machines; etc. For an introduction to the subject see the WP article on textile manufacturing.

Yes, but you set up the question with a fairly irrational way to accomplish your need. If you wanted a different solution, you should have set up a scenario where the obvious answer was not 'import clothes'.

Slight frame challenge:
The Medieval world already has what it takes to produce your uniforms with a few tweaks. You do not need fancy modern machinery, as long as you have peasants.

Fiber. Cotton is great and all, but it is one of the most finicky, and labor intensive fibers. Simple trick to instantly quandruple cotton porduction is to introdue the cotton gin (cotton engine) to make the combing of cotton much faster. However, this is still not efficient and cheap enough. Solution: wood fiber. The medieval world has orders of magnitude more woodland than farmland. The people know how to make fiber out of linden underbark, and several other tree barks, they just rarely do so. Normally, wood fiber is used for ropes and bags. But there is no problem converting it into cloth fiber, no worse than linen or hemp. Wood fiber would be order of magnitude cheaper as long as you have human labor available, and you can always upgrade it by mixing in linen, hemp, cotton or wool fibers. A harder trick, but still doable, is to dissolve the wood and draw cellulose fiber. It is possible, if hard, to just make ryon or viscose in the Middle Ages, and it might still be cheaper than importing or growing cotton. Finally, you can always make paper or wood-fiber felt, and waterproof it with wood-pitch. it would be crude but functional. Wood-fiber felt coated in thick pitch can also be formed into workman's galoshes (like the Soviet valonki). A side effect of making cloth out of trees is that you will also get abundant cloth dye out of bark tannins. As long as you are ok with your uniforms being shades of brown or grayish black, you can dye them to your heart's content.

Spinning thread. Introduce the idea of Spinning Jennies to every peasant household in your area. The are at least 7 times more efficient than hand-spinning. Bigger ones can be attached to watermills (without even sacrificing grain milling, as the spinner requires very little energy to spin, and can be attached in parallel).

Weaving. Your medieval society probably used vertical weighted looms in the rural areas, and simple horizontal looms in the towns. introduce them to a semi-vertical loom with a flying shuttle. The Flying shuttle speeds up weaving at least by a factor of 5, possibly 10 if the loom is well designed.


Finally, introduce the double-pointed needle. Sewing machines are probably too complex, but a Wisenthal's double needle can easily more than double the seamstresses output.
Waterproofing: you would be cutting down a lot f trees, so it will be easy to just make pitch out of them. But if you have access to natural oil fields, you can just use the firewood to boil the crude oils and achieve petroleum-based waterproofing oils (plus parafin) to coat the cloth with.
All of this can support your future machine, or can replace it entirely. All of the mentioned technologies either already exist in a medieval world, but aren't properly combined, or can be easily explained and built by any rural craftsman.
But there is more! Since your peasants can now draw and spin abundant fiber, there is no reason why you cannot introduce them to the idea of knitting and crocheting. Medieval people did not know knitting, they produced needlebound cloth instead (needlebinding is superior to knitting, and produces better clothes, but is order of magnitude slower). A well trained grandma can knit a sweater in two days, this is significantly faster than making tunics out of woven cloth. Sure, a crude sweater knitted out of scratchy and stiff linden fiber is not going to be all that pleasant to wear, but it would be extremely durable and warm. Normally, all those grandmas, grandpas, cripples and children to weak to do proper labor would spin thread, but since you just made spinning 7 times more efficient, you can have them knit sweaters, hoods, scarves, socks and work-mittens instead. Another nice thing about knitted clothes is that they are stretchy, so more "one size fits all" than woven tunics.
And once you have people comfortable with knitting, you can try to teach them how to make Jersey, which is knitted cloth but much finer.
Really, once you introduce these things, the uniforms problem will solve itself very quickly. Their ability to produce clothing will skyrocket on its own, but since population is stable in such a short timeline, they will all have abundant uniforms. I estimate they will be able to produce up to 14 times more clothing in a year than they normally would, more than enough to set them for a lifetime.
And as a bonus, since the technologies you introduced were simple, they will be able to use them and improve upon them even after you die.

"The medieval world has orders of magnitude more woodland than farmland": Nope, it does not. At least not anywhere west of Russia. Around say 1,100 a very heavily forested country such as for example Transylvania might have had about three times as much forest land as arable land plus grass land; but as population grew, by the end of the Middle Ages the forested area about the same size as the arable plus pasture area. Oh, and one or two sheep can easily give as much fiber as a birch tree, with the advantage that it can be woven into cloth and the sheep can repeat it year after year.

@AlexP, you are confusing Medieval World and Medieval Europe. Forests span over 30% of the entire world, and we just barely managed to cultivate more land than is forested in the last decades.  Yes, a sheep can give you more fiber than a birch, but most medieval kingdoms would have several orders of magnitude more trees than sheep, and they are logging these trees anyway for other projects. Either way, OP's problem is trivially solved by even a fraction of the fiber available, so it does not matter much.
